# Do I need a Time Series or Matrix or Vector or Data Frame?

Tags: r

I don't understand how the code below works.

```
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(BatchGetSymbols)
library(tidyr)
library(quantmod)
library(xts)
library(TTR)


ticker = 'AAPL'
# Get Data
# set dates
first.date <- Sys.Date() - 360
last.date <- Sys.Date()


out <- BatchGetSymbols(ticker = ticker, 
                       first.date = first.date,
                       last.date = last.date, 
                       cache.folder = file.path(tempdir(), 
                                                'BGS_Cache') ) 
out<-out$df.tickers
out<-out[,c("ref.date","ticker", "price.adjusted")]


##################################################################

# Eliminate Dupes
deduped_data <- unique(out[ , 1:3 ])

prices <- deduped_data$price.adjusted
prices <- as.data.frame(prices)


# Calculate Returns: Daily RoC
stock_ret <- ROC(prices, type = "discrete")


stock_ret <- as.matrix(stock_ret)
stock_ret <- ROC(stock_ret, type = "discrete")



#Output Top 10 Drawdowns By Magnitude
table.Drawdowns(stock_ret, top = 10, digits = 4)

paste("Average Drawdown",sprintf("%.2f %%", AverageDrawdown(stock_ret) * 100))
paste("Max Drawdown", sprintf("%.2f %%", maxDrawdown(stock_ret, geometric = TRUE) * 100))
paste("Drawdown Deviation",sprintf("%.2f %%", DrawdownDeviation(stock_ret) * 100))
paste("Average Length", round(AverageLength(stock_ret), 2))
paste("Average Recovery Time",round(AverageRecovery(stock_ret), 2))
```

When I get to the line below I get an error.

```
table.Drawdowns(stock_ret, top = 10, digits = 4)

Error in R[, 1, drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Apparently, something is wrong with the variable 'stock_ret'!

Any idea what is wrong here?  The code comes from the link below.

http://programmingforfinance.com/2017/11/examining-drawdowns-and-the-pain-index-with-r/

Comment: can you check `str(stock_ret)` or `dim(stock_ret)`?

Comment: The code in the link has `stock_ret <- dailyReturn(stock, type='arithmetic')` to create an xts object. How are you doing this - I'm not seeing it in the example?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you can just convert to an xts object.  That seems to be the most straightforward way.  The xts object needs a date index.

quantmod might have a wrapper for this already.  If there is, that would be cleaner.

Default options are used because you obviously can handle that part.

```
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(BatchGetSymbols)
library(tidyr)
library(quantmod)
library(xts)
library(TTR)
ticker = 'AAPL'
# Get Data
# set dates
first.date <- Sys.Date() - 360
last.date <- Sys.Date()
out <- BatchGetSymbols(ticker = ticker, 
                       first.date = first.date,
                       last.date = last.date, 
                       cache.folder = file.path(tempdir(), 
                                                'BGS_Cache') ) 
tickers <-out$df.tickers
# Create and xts object as suggested by many of the comments
prices.xts <- xts(tickers$ret.adjusted.prices, order.by = tickers$ref.date)
str(prices.xts)
table.Drawdowns(prices.xts)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out.  Your code threw a few errors: Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘2018-06-11’, ‘2018-06-12’ Error in checkData(R[, 1, drop = FALSE]) : 
  The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'.

Comment: I think I figure out another way to do it.  I'll post back if I can get this working.  It's too late to finish this off today.  I need to sleep now, and come back to this tomorrow.